# Use fancy QT Quick Effects from C++

Tags: qt, qt-quick

Is there a way to use things like Shader Effects, Particles, Sprites etc. without using QT Quick ? I'd like to make use of these effects but using only C++ code in, for example, a QGraphicsView.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Qt provides ability to implement reach graphics via C++ code.

You need to take a look at [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/graphicsview.html).

Also there are nice examples provided with Qt. E.g. in Qt 4.8.3 I'd suggest to look at *Graphics View* and *Painting* partitions.

Comment: That does cover most of what i need but i can't find a way to add particle emitters in C++ code...